# Extract All Lines within a File that Matches Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, perl, unix

I have a 50k line file which contains dig command output; I'm wanting to extract all lines which match the regex of all IPv4 private network classes (RFC1918). An example is provided below with mock-up values for demonstration:

**The main input file:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19663
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     135 IN  A   192.168.0.1

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 12 17:40:16 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> transfer.me
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7906
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;transfer.me.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
transfer.me.        7200    IN  A   10.216.41.127

;; Query time: 588 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 12 17:40:36 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

The expected output that is desired:

```
google.com.     135 IN  A   192.168.0.1
transfer.me.        7200    IN  A   10.216.41.127
```

I already have the regular expressions, so it is just a question of how to put it all together to obtain the desired output.

Class A Networks:

```
(10)(\.([2]([0-5][0-5]|[01234][6-9])|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3}
```

Class B Network:

```
(172)\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}
```

Class C Network:

```
(192)\.(168)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}
```

Would appreciate assistance with either UNIX CLI utilities, or even better Python, or Perl scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special about this problem.

You have already defined regex for each network class let's put it to use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $re_classA = qr/(10)(\.([2]([0-5][0-5]|[01234][6-9])|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3}/;
my $re_classB = qr/(172)\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}/;
my $re_classC = qr/(192)\.(168)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}/;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^;/;
    say if /$re_classA/;
    say if /$re_classB/;
    say if /$re_classC/;
}

__DATA__

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19663
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     135 IN  A   192.168.0.1

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 12 17:40:16 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> transfer.me
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7906
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;transfer.me.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
transfer.me.        7200    IN  A   10.216.41.127

;; Query time: 588 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue May 12 17:40:36 AEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Output

```
google.com.     135 IN  A   192.168.0.1
transfer.me.        7200    IN  A   10.216.41.127
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly what I was after.

Comment: @Jase -- `next if /^;/;` can be replaced with `next unless /^[^;].*?\d{2,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b/;` - process line only if it not starts with `;` and may have anything followed with IP address (2 or 3 digits followed with `.` then one to three digits followed with `.` followed with 1 to 3 digits followed with `.` followed with 1 to 3 digits).